# Print specific values from a dictionary, then go to the next line

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now I am manually typing in every single key for the print lines at the bottom like this :

```
grid = {}
coord = {}
gridRender = {}

yCoord = -10

for xGrid in range(-5, 6):
    for yGrid in range(-5, 6):
        gridRender[xGrid, yGrid] = "░░"
        gridRender[0, yGrid] = "▒▒"
        gridRender[xGrid, 0] = "▒▒"

for xCoord in range(-5, 6):
    try:
        yCoord = round(sin(xCoord))
    except:
        yCoord = -10
    gridRender[xCoord, yCoord] = "██"

print(gridRender[-5, 5] + gridRender[-4, 5] + gridRender[-3, 5] + gridRender[-2, 5] + gridRender[-1, 5] + gridRender[0, 5] + gridRender[1, 5] + gridRender[2, 5] + gridRender[3, 5] + gridRender[4, 5] + gridRender[5, 5])
print(gridRender[-5, 4] + gridRender[-4, 4] + gridRender[-3, 4] + gridRender[-2, 4] + gridRender[-1, 4] + gridRender[0, 4] + gridRender[1, 4] + gridRender[2, 4] + gridRender[3, 4] + gridRender[4, 4] + gridRender[5, 4])
print(gridRender[-5, 3] + gridRender[-4, 3] + gridRender[-3, 3] + gridRender[-2, 3] + gridRender[-1, 3] + gridRender[0, 3] + gridRender[1, 3] + gridRender[2, 3] + gridRender[3, 3] + gridRender[4, 3] + gridRender[5, 3])
print(gridRender[-5, 2] + gridRender[-4, 2] + gridRender[-3, 2] + gridRender[-2, 2] + gridRender[-1, 2] + gridRender[0, 2] + gridRender[1, 2] + gridRender[2, 2] + gridRender[3, 2] + gridRender[4, 2] + gridRender[5, 2])
print(gridRender[-5, 1] + gridRender[-4, 1] + gridRender[-3, 1] + gridRender[-2, 1] + gridRender[-1, 1] + gridRender[0, 1] + gridRender[1, 1] + gridRender[2, 1] + gridRender[3, 1] + gridRender[4, 1] + gridRender[5, 1])
print(gridRender[-5, 0] + gridRender[-4, 0] + gridRender[-3, 0] + gridRender[-2, 0] + gridRender[-1, 0] + gridRender[0, 0] + gridRender[1, 0] + gridRender[2, 0] + gridRender[3, 0] + gridRender[4, 0] + gridRender[5, 0])
print(gridRender[-5, -1] + gridRender[-4, -1] + gridRender[-3, -1] + gridRender[-2, -1] + gridRender[-1, -1] + gridRender[0, -1] + gridRender[1, -1] + gridRender[2, -1] + gridRender[3, -1] + gridRender[4, -1] + gridRender[5, -1])
print(gridRender[-5, -2] + gridRender[-4, -2] + gridRender[-3, -2] + gridRender[-2, -2] + gridRender[-1, -2] + gridRender[0, -2] + gridRender[1, -2] + gridRender[2, -2] + gridRender[3, -2] + gridRender[4, -2] + gridRender[5, -2])
print(gridRender[-5, -3] + gridRender[-4, -3] + gridRender[-3, -3] + gridRender[-2, -3] + gridRender[-1, -3] + gridRender[0, -3] + gridRender[1, -3] + gridRender[2, -3] + gridRender[3, -3] + gridRender[4, -3] + gridRender[5, -3])
print(gridRender[-5, -4] + gridRender[-4, -4] + gridRender[-3, -4] + gridRender[-2, -4] + gridRender[-1, -4] + gridRender[0, -4] + gridRender[1, -4] + gridRender[2, -4] + gridRender[3, -4] + gridRender[4, -4] + gridRender[5, -4])
print(gridRender[-5, -5] + gridRender[-4, -5] + gridRender[-3, -5] + gridRender[-2, -5] + gridRender[-1, -5] + gridRender[0, -5] + gridRender[1, -5] + gridRender[2, -5] + gridRender[3, -5] + gridRender[4, -5] + gridRender[5, -5])
```

However this seems like an unnecessarily long way of doing this and if I wanted to make the grid any bigger, it would take a while to type in every value. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop and `join()`

```
for y_coord in range(5, -6, -1):
    print(''.join(gridRender[x_coord, y_coord] for x_coord in range(-5, 6)))
```